# Fetch data via socket.io. Setting: token; error: invalid credentials

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, axios, es6-promise

I have the token `const token = 'abcdefgh'`. In the app.jsx file, I put it in the headers

```
headers: {
       Authorization: `Bearer $ {token}`
     }
```

I can fetch the data without problems.

---

When I put a token in the file `app.js` -->  server. I have error:

> Your request was made with invalid credentials.

```
const token = 'abcdefgh';

const get = async socket => {
    try {
        const res = await axios("https://todos.com/api/v1/todos", {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                'token': token
            }
        }); 
        socket.emit("API", res.data); 
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("error:- ",error);
    }
};
```

Comment: a header named `token` is not the same as header named `Authorization`

Comment: also, adding `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` suggests you are trying to overcome a CORS error - adding a **response** header in a **request** doesn't help

Comment: @JaromandaX   I changed `token` to `Authorization`. Delete `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` but I have still error: `error: 'Your request was made with invalid credentials.' `

Comment: you probably have invalid credentials - can you show **exactly** what you are doing now that you've changed things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to send `Authorization` - but in your request, it's `token`.

```
'token': token
```

Send the correct header name or the server won't see your credentials.

```
Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
```

Comment: I have still error `error: 'Your request was made with invalid credentials.' `

Comment: clearly it should be `Authorization: \`Bearer ${token}\``